# Capturing logging message returned from server in a string variable

Tags: logging

I am using the logging utility with python.  I need to capture some of the returned messages from the remote server into a string variable so that I can parse it and get information which is to be used later.  I have found no way to do this short of stopping the logger, opening the og file, then scanning line-by-line until I find the appropriate information.  I am sure there is another way to do this, but the documentation is very obtuse in this regard.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks
-William